# How do I display Images in React from a Django Rest API?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I want to send my images from the django media folder to my react front end. And the view I build works when I go to the Url 'api/id/1' the image gets displayed but when I want to open it in my react app under loacalhost:8000 the image is not being displayed

the view

```
class PNGRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'image/png'
    format = 'png'
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data


class ImageAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Images.objects.filter(id=1)
    renderer_classes = [PNGRenderer]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        renderer_classes = [PNGRenderer]
        queryset = Images.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id']).image
        data = queryset
        return Response(data, content_type='image/png')
```

the API call

```
export function apiImage(image,callback) {
    const endpoint = `id/${image}`
    backendlookup('GET', endpoint ,callback)  
}

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  
  

  const handleLookup = (response, status) => {
    if (status === 200) {
        console.log(response)
    }
  }
    
      

  const [img, setImg]=useState(apiImage(2,handleLookup))
  
  const ImgChange =(e) =>{
    if(e === 'laugh'){
      setImg(Trainer_Laugh)
    }
    if(e === 'smile'){
      setImg(Trainer_Smile)
    }
  }

  return (
    
      <Grid container display="flex" direction="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" className={classes.grid}>
          <img src={img} alt='girl' className={classes.img}/> 
            <Paper className={classes.paper} >
              <Textfield handleWaifuChange={ImgChange}/>
            </Paper>
      </Grid>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you return undefined from the function that calls API

```
export function apiImage(image,callback) {
    const endpoint = `id/${image}`
    backendlookup('GET', endpoint ,callback)  
}
```

You need to return

```
export function apiImage(image,callback) {
    const endpoint = `id/${image}`
    return backendlookup('GET', endpoint ,callback)  
}
```

Also, the API call should be the asynchronous call. Thus you get the promise pending object in your state instead of the result.

```
const [img, setImg]=useState(apiImage(2,handleLookup))
```

You must wait for the result before populating the state. You can do it like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [img, setImg]=useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  async fetchData() {
    const img = await apiImage(2,handleLookup);
    setImg(img);
  }
```

If it doesn't work, check whether the `backendlookup` sends the server request properly. If it doesn't work again, check the server API, put the related API path in your browser URI and see if you get the expected output.

You can read more about the promises here https://javascript.info/async And read about the React useEffect here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html